# tableview not being displayed

Tags: android, twitter, titanium

I'm using the code bird library to integrate a twitter feed into a titanium app. At the minute I'm only interested in text and an image. I am getting these elements fine in the console and my entire code is getting no errors, however, the table is not appearing in the app. I have replaced the key and secret key with correct values. See code below:

```
var tableView= Titanium.UI.createTableView({
        zIndex:60
    });
var rowData;

var win= Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor:"white"
});


var Codebird = require("codebird");
var cb = new Codebird();
cb.setConsumerKey('consumer key', 'consumer secret');

var bearerToken = Ti.App.Properties.getString('TwitterBearerToken', null);
if(bearerToken == null){
    cb.__call(
        'oauth2_token',
        {},
        function (reply) {
            var bearer_token = reply.access_token;
            cb.setBearerToken(bearer_token);
            Ti.App.Properties.setString('TwitterBearerToken', bearer_token);
            fetchTwitter();
        }
    );
}
else {
    Ti.API.info("We do have a bearer token...----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    cb.setBearerToken(bearerToken);
    fetchTwitter();
}

function fetchTwitter(){
    var data = [];


    cb.__call(
        'statuses/user_timeline',
        "screen_name=ClassicHits4FM",
        function (reply) {
            // ...
            Ti.API.info("newest and Example that should work just reply------------------------------"+ reply);
            Ti.API.info("newest and Example that may work, reply's text ------------------------------"+ reply[0].text);
            Ti.API.info("newest and Example that may work, reply's text ------------------------------"+ reply[0].user.profile_image_url);


            for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            data.push({    
                title: reply[i].text,
                leftImage:reply[0].user.profile_image_url         
            });
            //alert("Data test ----------------------------------"+data[i].title);

            }

            //Ti.API.info("newest Example that should work, user profile image ------------------------------"+ reply[0].user[0].profile_image_url);

        },
        true // this parameter required
    );

    rowData=[];

    for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        var img= Titanium.UI.createImageView({
                image:data[i].leftImage,
                left:5,
                bottom:5,
                top:5,
                height: '120dp',
                width: '120dp'
                //height: "120%",
                //width: "34%"
            });

        var title=Titanium.UI.createLabel({
                text:data[i].title,
                color: 'black',
                //left: "38%",
                left: '128dp',
                right: '4dp',
                font:{ fontSize: '15sp', font: 'Droid Serif'}
            });


        var row=Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
            height: TI.UI.SIZE
            });

        row.add(img);
        row.add(title);
        rowData.push(row);  
    }

    tableView.setData(rowData);
    win.add(tableView);
}

win.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tableView= Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    zIndex:60,
    width : Ti.UI.FILL,
    height: Ti.UI.FILL
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem, by moving all code from 'rowdata' onwards into the 'cb.__call' statement block.

Also, in my row definition I had written **TI.UI.SIZE** which needed to be **Ti.UI.SIZE**